# Found nil while unwrapping CellViewWithTag UICollectionView

Tags: ios, tags, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have used UITableViews so I can't see what the difference is.

So my Storyboard is set up like this:

[image]

With Identifier

[image]

And the Tags set up like this

[image]

[image]

And my code is like this:

class MoreController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

```
    @IBOutlet var moreCollection: UICollectionView!

    var moreitems = [  [ MoreItem(title: "Maps", imageUrl: "Map Marker-25.png"), MoreItem(title: "Dart", imageUrl: "Train-25.png"), MoreItem(title: "Feedback", imageUrl: "Feedback-25.png"), MoreItem(title: "Help", imageUrl: "High Priority-25.png")  ]  ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 52/255, green: 138/255, blue: 169/255, alpha: 1.0)

        moreCollection.delegate = self
        moreCollection.dataSource = self

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return moreitems.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return moreitems[section].count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MoreCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

        let icLab = cell.viewWithTag(4001) as! UILabel
        let imView = cell.viewWithTag(4002) as! UIImageView

        icLab.text = moreitems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].title
        imView.image = UIImage(named: moreitems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].imageUrl)

        return cell
    }
}
```

I am getting the errors `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` on the lines:

`let icLab = cell.viewWithTag(4001) as! UILabel` and

`let imView = cell.viewWithTag(4002) as! UIImageView`

Any idea why?

Comment: did you tried `let icLab = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(4001) as! UILabel `?

Comment: same error unfortunately :/

Comment: Breakpoint and log the cell, subviews and tags - what do you see

Comment: Not entirely sure how to do this, still a beginner